# extract a specific field from array in Google Sheets

Tags: arrays, indexing, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I am executing a function in Google Sheets which is resulting into an array output like below

```
Col1   Col2

A        B

10       20
```

What I want is to fetch only 20 and I don't want other rows and columns to be printed. I tried using function array_contrain but that will always print the first column and row. 
Is there any way to get only a single field from an array.

Comment: Hi there - please check out the SO guides on posting questions.  In particular, here can you post what code you've tried - that way you'll be more likely to get people trying to help.  thanks!

Comment: Do you want to get only 20 or you only to get 1 field for the array? if you want an array you can use {A1:A3 ;B1:B3 } , and please show us your attemp

Answer (score 8, accepted):

use `INDEX` or wrap your formula into `INDEX` instead of `ARRAY_CONSTRAIN`

for example:

```
=INDEX(A:B, 3, 2)
```

[image: 0]

Answer (score 2):

[image: Result]

This will get each cell in a1:a4 and b1:b4 that has value 20 (in one field):

```
=query(ARRAYFORMULA({if(A1:A4=20,20,0);if(B1:B4=20,20,0)}),"Select Col1 where Col1=20")
```